# How can I combine code of the two jQuery functions to reduce execution time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I've following two functions. First one is written for auto complete functionality and second one is written for checking whether user has selected the value from the auto populated list or not. But as I've used the same AJAX functionality in both of the functions it's taking too much time in completing the execution. Can someone please help me in optimizing the code I written by making a single function?

My code is as follows:

```
$('.dynamic_cat').keyup(function() {
  $(".dynamic_cat").typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
      var textVal   = $(".dynamic_cat").val();
      var admin_url = $("#admin_url").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: admin_url+'modules/product_types/product_types.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'op=get_all_categories',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
          process(data);        
        }
      });
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dynamic_cat').blur(function() {
    if( $('.dynamic_cat').val() ) {  
      var textVal   = $(".dynamic_cat").val();
      var admin_url = $("#admin_url").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: admin_url+'modules/product_types/product_types.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'op=get_all_categories',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
          if($.inArray(textVal, data) == -1) {
            alert("Please select the value from list only!!!");
            $('.dynamic_cat').val("");
          }      
        }
      });
    } 
  });  
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just save the result of the AJAX request in a Javascript variable and use that in both functions, if it is `!= undefined`. If it is undefined, make the AJAX request and save the result. // You can extend that with a timestamp variable, if you need more or less current data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use typeahead:selected event, to set a variable, if value is selected from list, reset the varible on keyup in textbox, then on blur, check if variable is set to true else alert the user.

[Typeahead custom events](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events)

[Demo link complete example](http://jsbin.com/putekeka/1)

Something like:

```
var isItemSelectedFromTypeAhead = false;

$('.dynamic_cat').keyup(function() {
//On keyup reset it
  isItemSelectedFromTypeAhead = false;
  $(".dynamic_cat").typeahead({
   source: function(query, process) {
   var textVal   = $(".dynamic_cat").val();
   var admin_url = $("#admin_url").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: admin_url+'modules/product_types/product_types.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'op=get_all_categories',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
      process(data);        
    }
  });
}
  }).on('typeahead:selected', function(obj, selected, name) {
  //Something is selected from typeahead
  isItemSelectedFromTypeAhead = true;
  });

$('.dynamic_cat').blur(function() {
  var curValue = $(this).val();
  if(curValue !== "" && !isItemSelectedFromTypeAhead)
  {
    alert("Please select the value from list only!!!");
    $('.dynamic_cat').val("");
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but in a function called on blur event, the value of variable "isItemSelectedFromTypeAhead" is always coming false. It's not getting updated to true even if I select value from drop down list only. If I enter some other value than values present in list then it should be false. What should be done to rectify this issue?

Comment: Can you check if event 'typeahead:selected' is getting called?

Comment: You spotted the error and my point exactly. I checked by placing alert in 'typeahead:selected'. It's not getting called after I select any value from the matching list of items. How should we resolve this?

Comment: Still it's not getting called. May I know where you did modifications to your code?

Comment: the event binding part. It was not closed properly. .on('typeahead:selected',function(){.... });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58788/discussion-between-ssa-and-user2839497).